# Is blood donation permissible?

Tags: halal-haram, blood

Is it permitted to donate blood to blood banks in Islam?

Blood donation is different from blood [tranfusion](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23413/what-is-the-stance-of-islam-on-blood-transfusion?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Is it allowed to donate blood to blood banks where the bloods are stored for future use?

Comment: That question is newer, but [that's okay](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147643/266429). It's also slightly broader, but not even close to "too broad." Otherwise it's an exact duplicate, so I think it makes sense to close this one as a dupe of the other.

Comment: See also: [Is it permissible to donate blood?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36517/17163).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is permissible - donating and receiving blood from/to muslims and non-muslims... see [here](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/958) and [here](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/239).

Allah knows best.