# Is donating blood or bone marrow forbidden in Islam?

Tags: halal-haram, medical

Is donating blood or bone marrow forbidden in Islam? If yes then why and are there any scientific proof?

Comment: Please clarify the specifics of the donation? From? To? How? And why? As you can see from this [fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/2320) that it can be contextual. If human to human, it is generally allowed irrespective of any other considerations apart from harm or during war (see this [fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/12729)). The same applies to other types of donation (see [bone marrow](https://islamqa.info/en/152447) and [stem cells](https://islamqa.info/en/108125)) fatwas).

Comment: Answers are not clear from the link you attached. Somewhere it states that the needy man should be Muslim, the doctor should be Muslim. I am asking whether it is permissible for a Muslim to donate blood in blood donation camp where he/she don't know who is going to get that blood.

Comment: These are two different things I'm pretty sure that the matter of  blood donation is covered at least once on the site see for instance https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36517/is-it-permissible-to-donate-blood?rq=1!

Answer (score -1):

Muslims are recommended to donate blood to muslims and  to those who don't wage war against Islam and Muslims.

Donation of organs post death /bone marrow same scenario applies.

A muslim is adviced against donating blood in a blood donation camp as the recipient is unknown.

Comment: Any surah or ayah supporting your answer! @Preordainment