# Is it considered as a good charity to donate blood to someone in need?

Tags: practical-islam, medical, sadaqah

Is it considered to be a good charity to donate blood to someone in need. Is it permissible or is it encouraged in Islam? Also is it considered as a charity in Islam?

Comment: I think your inquiry is covered in the answers of [Is it permissible to donate blood?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36517/is-it-permissible-to-donate-blood)

Answer (score 1):

I'll extract the relevant parts of [my answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/37290/17163) to [Is it permissible to donate blood?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36517/17163)

Some fatawa say blood donation is a rewardable act, such as:

> ... whoever donates his blood to save the lives of people, indeed, he gets a good reward for that if he does so for the sake of Allah
> <sub>[IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=87533)</sub>
>
> ... there is nothing wrong with giving blood to him as an act of charity, and you will be rewarded for that ...
> <sub>[Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/129113)</sub>

None of the fatawa I looked at contradicted these fatawa, in general.  However, there were some precautions, such as the blood not being used for impermissible things ([IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=129802)).  See the linked answer for more stipulated conditions.